# How to export a PDF from composer when I use the Google Physical layer as a basemap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf, google

I am unable to open a new map I've just made in print composer if I use the Google Physical basemap layer. After I export the map I've made and try to open it on my desktop, it reads that the PDF is damaged and cannot be opened. I tried using other topographic base maps from the open layers plugin as well and had similar problems. The export works perfectly fine with arial and hybrid layers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the openlayers plugin?

Comment: Use the Quick Map Services plugin instead.

Comment: @ndawson yes I am using open layers.